# Facebook SDK works on emulator but doesn't on real Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to allow my user login with it's FB account. Everything works fine on my emulator, but when i try to test it on real iphone i get an error as popup

> domain=com.facebook.sdk code=5

It first goes to FB app with only blue line on above and nothing more on the screen stays like that a few seconds and then goes back to my app and gives my the error i listed above.
What is different in sdk work on iphone and on computer?
Please help me!

Comment: Are you working on sandbox mode ? Do you have facebook app installed ? What iOS version you are working on on real device ?

Comment: What is sandbox mode? I do have FB app. iOS is 6.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox mode is explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

If you're trying to allow someone other than yourself to test the app, using their Facebook account, you'll have to add them as a developer or tester in the Facebook developer portal.